# Iterating values of multiple rows in table in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a code to fetch the details of the values selected by the user. The code works fine and shows the array. The only problem is that is displays error   for childnodes. Where am I doing it wrong?

```
function add_checkout_details(){
           var total = $("#total").val();
           var product_id = new Array();
           var qty = new Array();
           var price = new Array();
           var amount = new Array();

           var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
           var rowCount = table.rows.length;    
         for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {

                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var txtBox0 = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
                    var txtBox1 = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
                    var txtBox2 = row.cells[3].childNodes[0].value;
                    var txtBox3 = row.cells[4].childNodes[0].value;
                    var txtBox4 = row.cells[8].childNodes[0].value;

                     product_id.push(txtBox0);
                     qty.push(txtBox1);
                     price.push(txtBox2);
                     amount.push(txtBox3);
                    }



    $.post('controller/add_checkout_details.php',{'product_id[]':product_id,'qty[]':qty,'price[]':price,'amount[]':amount,total:total}, function(data){

        $('#error').text(data);
    });
    }
```

Comment: can you add how your table looks like in code?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes do not have a `value` property. Instead use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).

```
row.cells[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Note that you can write this as:

```
row.cells[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

See also [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), which have slightly different behaviour.